# How to create custome tab view like below

Tags: android, tabview

Gone through many websites before posting my question. Please help. I am currently working on enterprise application. I want to design my application with all the new UI. Some tab views are required for me in my app to show different types of invoices. I would like to have the tab view exactly as the below shown screenshot. Of course this is an ios screenshot but i want that in android. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Its  a not too much hard to implement. Atleast try  something from your end!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can custom.
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

```
 //Set the pager with an adapter
 ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
 pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

 //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
 TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
 titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

With, view pager call Fragment detail.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
 pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

Use the Custom layout to tabs and on page changeListner set the layout background. (Use can also use Selector for this).